# How to use local variables in other functions?

Tags: python, regex, scope

I want to print the result in a separate function however when I call the variables I cannot use them because they are in a different function. Can anyone show me how to edit my code so this works? p.s. I know I should use beautifulsoup... however, Im having trouble getting it to install on my computer

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re
import cookielib
from cookielib import CookieJar
import time
c_j = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(c_j))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')] #Makes the website think we are       using firefox by using header

def proxies1():
      try:
          page = 'http://free-proxy-list.net/' #Sets the variable page as our website
          sourceCode = opener.open(page).read() #Reads the source code
          titles = re.findall('<tr><td>(.*?)</td><td>', sourceCode) #Parses the Html, collects the proxies
     for title in titles:
         proxy1 = title.replace(',', '').replace("!", '').replace(":", '').replace(";", '') 
     except Exception, e:

         print str(e)

def ports1():
      try:
        page = 'http://free-proxy-list.net/' #Sets the variable page as our website
        sourceCode = opener.open(page).read() #Reads the source code
        banana = re.findall('</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>', sourceCode) #Parses the Html, collects the proxies
        for title in banana:
              port1 = title.replace('a', '').replace('b', '').replace('c', '').replace('d', '').replace('e', '').replace('f', '').replace('g', '').replace('h', '') \
  .replace('i', '').replace('j', '').replace('k', '').replace('l', '').replace('m', '').replace('n', '').replace('o', '').replace('p', '') \
  .replace('q', '').replace('r', '').replace('s', '').replace('t', '').replace('u', '').replace('v', '').replace('w', '').replace('x', '') \
  .replace('y', '').replace('z', '').replace('A', '').replace('B', '').replace('C', '').replace('D', '').replace('E', '').replace('F', '').replace('G', '') \
  .replace('H', '').replace('I', '').replace('J', '').replace('K', '').replace('L', '').replace('M', '').replace('N', '').replace('O', '') \
  .replace('P', '').replace('Q', '').replace('R', '').replace('S', '').replace('T', '').replace('U', '').replace('V', '').replace('W', '') \
  .replace('X', '').replace('Y', '').replace('Z', '')
  except Exception, e:
    print str(e)



def printfun():

      print str(proxy1) + ":" + str(port1)

printfun()
```

I know my indentation is off a bit, stack overflow messed it up.... How can I do this?

Comment: If you can't use BeautifulSoup, there are HTML/XML parsers in the standard library. They may not be quite as easy to use as bs, but they're a lot easier than writing custom regexps—and they don't have all the problems you get trying to parse a non-regular language with regexps.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly which variables you want to use from one function in the other, so I wrote a sort of general answer. If you make the question more specific, I could make my answer more specific as well.

Comment: In the future, use the [re library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) to do string replacements with regular expressions: `title = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]', '', title)` is much easier to read than replace() 50 times.

Comment: `findall` will return a list and if there is more than one match, `port1` and `proxy1` will have only the last matched values. Is that what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a local variable from one function in another function. That is, in fact, the whole *point* of local variables.

You *could* change things by using global variables instead, but that's a bad idea.

However, a similar idea, with all the same benefits but without the problems, is to use object attributes. Change the two functions into methods of a class, and change the variables into attributes on that class. Like this:

```
class ProxyParser(object):
    def proxies1(self):
          try:
              self.page = 'http://free-proxy-list.net/' #Sets the variable page as our website
              self.sourceCode = opener.open(page).read() #Reads the source code
              self.titles = re.findall('<tr><td>(.*?)</td><td>', sourceCode) #Parses the Html, collects the proxies
         for title in self.titles:
             proxy1 = title.replace(',', '').replace("!", '').replace(":", '').replace(";", '') 
         except Exception, e:

             print str(e)
def ports1(self):
    try:
        for title in self.titles:
            # etc.

proxy_parser = ProxyParser()
proxy_parser.proxies1()
proxy_parser.ports1()
```

Basically, just stick a `self` at the start of the parameter list of each function, and a `self.` before each of the local variables, and now they're instance variables instead, which are shared by all methods of that object, instead of being local to each separate function.

---

A different alternative is to `return` values from one function, and then pass them to the other as arguments. Like this:

```
def proxies1():
      try:
          page = 'http://free-proxy-list.net/' #Sets the variable page as our website
          sourceCode = opener.open(page).read() #Reads the source code
          titles = re.findall('<tr><td>(.*?)</td><td>', sourceCode) #Parses the Html, collects the proxies
     for title in titles:
         proxy1 = title.replace(',', '').replace("!", '').replace(":", '').replace(";", '')
     except Exception, e:

         print str(e)
     return titles

def ports1(titles):
    for title in titles:
         # etc.

titles = proxies1()
ports1(titles)
```

---

Meanwhile, while your question asked about using the variables from one function in the other function, I think what you *actually* want is to use them from outside both functions. Fortunately, the exact same solutions work just as well for that: either `return` the values you want to use, or store them as instance attributes.

However, before you can get there… you have to actually *have* the values that you want. Your `proxies` function just redefines the `proxy1` variable over and over. So, even if you `return proxy1`, it's just going to be the last one in the page. And likewise, your `ports1` function does the same with `port1`.

I'm still not sure exactly what you want to do here, but probably you want to return *all* of the proxies. You can do this by building a list and returning that—or, if you're feeling adventurous, but `yield`ing each one. Then, your caller can get a list (or iterator) of proxies from one function, and a list (or iterator) of ports from the other, `zip` them together, and loop over the result. Like this:

```
proxies = proxies1()
ports = ports1()
for proxy, port in zip(proxies, ports):
    print proxy + ':' + port
```

Comment: Thats a bit complicated. Im still a noobie here. Mind doing the entire code over so I can look it over and learn from it?

Comment: @Ungifted: For the second version, literally the only thing you have to do to finish it is to replace that `# etc.` with all of the rest of your code.

Comment: Can we reduce the `.replace()` madness with `str.translate()` too here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Sure, with an identity table and a single deletechars string. And we could use an HTML parser instead of regexp, or a simpler regexp. And, since we're only reading a single page and never talking to the site again, we could dispense with the cookie jar, meaning we can also drop the opener. And the indentation should be consistent. And so on. Lots of ways to improve this, but I don't want to overwhelm the OP…

Comment: @MartijnPieters: And an even better improvement would be to parse the alternating titles and ports in one go, instead of downloading and parsing the page for the titles, then re-downloading and parsing the same page for the ports…

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to print out a list of proxy:port addresses? This should help with that:

```
import urllib2
from urllib2 import urlopen
import re
import cookielib
from cookielib import CookieJar
import time
c_j = CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(c_j))
opener.addheaders = [('User-agent','Mozilla/5.0')]

def proxies():
      page = 'http://free-proxy-list.net/'
      sourceCode = opener.open(page).read()
      proxy_ports = re.findall('<tr><td>(.*?)</td><td>(.*?)</td><td>', sourceCode)
      addresses = []
      for pp in proxy_ports:
            addresses.append("%s:%s" % pp)
      return addresses

print "\n".join(proxies())
```